# ElasticSearch bool query - hundred of OR terms

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, query-string

I need to verify and find the respective entries, that matches to a huge list of (in my case) verbs. 
For example: I have 200 statements in a csv and need to find the matching items in my index.
I can only find **bool** and **query-string** examples, but it would get REALLY ugly to write down 200 seperate statements and connect them with OR (or should).

Is there a smart way to do that? Maybe with some bash magic?

Many thanks and thanks for the input, cheers
Jonas

Comment: did you check the `terms` keyword of Elasticsearch?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html to be exact though this will only work for not analyzed terms.

Comment: wow this looks really promising - so I basically just build a new index with my search-terms and check against this index? Will try that and give a review later :-)

Answer (score 0):

**terms** was the right approach. I simply create a second index with an Array of X-verbs and combine it in the terms-query
thanks a lot!